# Default timeout of CSRF in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form, csrf, zend-form-element, csrf-protection

Is it possible to specify a global default timeout for CSRF form elements in Zend 2?
Otherwise I have to specify a timeout option for each CSRF element.

P.S.: What's the value of the current default timeout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the source code of [Zend\Validator\Csrf](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Validator/Csrf.php#L70), the default timeout of `Csrf` element in Zend Framework 2 is set to `300`:

```
protected $timeout = 300; //line 70
```

If you want to set the same time out for all Csrf elements in your forms, you could create a custom `csrfValidator` with the timeout value you want and override the default CSRF validator of your elements using `setCsrfValidator` method.

Otherwise just change the default options when you add Csrf element to your forms:

> You can change the options of the CSRF validator using the `setCsrfValidatorOptions` function, or by using the `csrf_options` key.
>
> [Csrf documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.element.csrf.html#csrf)

Answer (score 1):

I have my own Form base class, derived off `Zend\Form\From` that all my forms inherit from.  This way I can have some default behavior for all forms.  Specifically, the one thing I have in this base class for now is that all forms are given a CSRF element by default.  This way I never forget to add one.  And, if you are doing this, then you could easily configure whatever time-out you want in that one place and it would apply to all your forms.